# Group/Combine fields in backend and add another block?

Tags: fields

I'm looking for a way to combine/group channel fields plus the ability to
add another punch/block of them.

I know you can group fields in tabs but i need something like the plus in Matrix
where you can add a new row.

Comment: Please explain why Matrix does not do what you need.

Comment: In Matrix you can make rows with columns. But not a row with 3 columns and then another row underneath that row that spans this 3 columns.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to do - maybe we can suggest an alternate solution.